# How to create a short regular expression

Tags: regex

How to create a short regular expression which only matches words that don't have the same characters following after another.

It is only the following Syntax elements allowed to use:
. * + ? | ()

And the alphabet is as {a, b}

Example:

```
   Is matching: abababab

   Not matching: abbab
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you provide sample strings and expected output? Also, if you've made any attempt please include that as well.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 2):

Well, your exercise is not very clear (which regex engine are you using? etc),
but I managed to do something:

```
(?<=^|\P{L})(?:(\p{L})(?!\1))+(?=\P{L}|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/R2t2ik/1

**Explanation**

1. We are looking for a character of any type of language and not just `[a-z]`
   neither just the `\w` for a word character. This is because `àéêï` would
   typically not match. So instead, use `\p{L}` which is made for selecting
   specific Unicode classes.

   More details here:
   https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category
2. We will capture this char with a capturing group: `(\p{L})`
   This will create a match with the number 1. The match 0 is the match of the
   entire regular expression. Each capturing expression found from left to right
   will create a new numbered match. In our case we will then be able to refer
   our captured group with the `\1` reference.
3. To check if two following characters are not identical, we will use a
   negative lookahead, meaning that the searched item will not be selected
   if the lookahead results with a success.

   The regex becomes: `(\p{L})(?!\1)`

   This means: **"Find a letter of any language that is not followed by itself."**
4. Now, a word is made of one or more characters, so it could be matched with
   `\w+` but as explained before, this would only work in English. So in any
   language, it would become `(\p{L})+`. It seems that `\p{L}+` doesn't work
   properly, so adding a group around it will help the `+` to know what should
   appear once or more.

   Okay, that's good, but it's not what we want exactly. We only want to find
   characters that are not followed by themselves. So we have to use our
   pattern at point 3.

   This becomes: `(?:(\p{L})(?!\1))+`

   You would ask why do we have this `(?:` and `)` around all of it?
   Well, this is because we could simply use `(` and `)+` but in this case it
   would create a new capturing group, which we don't need. So to create a
   non-capturing group, you have to add the `?:` at the beginning.

   Capturing group = `(abc)` vs non-capturing group = `(?:abc)`
5. To finish, we want to capture word beginnings and ends with the help of
   a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead. I started with the usual
   `\b` for word **b**oundary but it did not work. Don't ask me why. I expect
   that it's related to the use of the Unicode classes or perhaps the way the
   selector is written. Someone may find an explanation, I'm not a specialist.

   Well, I had to solve that by trying to match either the begin of the string
   with the `^` selector and with the `\P{L}` Unicode class to select a char
   which is not a language character. I did the same for the end by using the
   `$` selector.

   So at the beginning, I added a positive lookbehind meaning "start with or
   has a non-letter char before" done with this `(?<=^|\P{L})` rule.

   And at the end, I added a positive lookahead meaning "finish with or has
   a non-letter char after" done with this `(?=\P{L}|$)` rule.
6. Putting everything together:
   `(?<=^|\P{L})`<sup>5</sup> + `(?:(\p{L})(?!\1))+`<sup>4</sup> +
   `(?=\P{L}|$)`<sup>5</sup> results in:
   `(?<=^|\P{L})(?:(\p{L})(?!\1))+(?=\P{L}|$)`

I hope it's what you where looking for and that it's not to complicated to
understand.

Comment: You should explain it more clearly. Break it down into steps and explain how each part works, since you're answering the question for a newbie. That's a very cryptic looking regex and I use them all the time.

Comment: Be aware that variable length lookbehind is not supported by all regex flavors.

Comment: @clearlight: You're right, I was in a hurry... I edited my answer and I hope it's easier to understand.

Comment: @Toto I think that `(?<=^|\P{L})` is considered as a "known lenght" so I don't think it should cause troubles, does it? I'm more afraid that the `\p{L}` will not be handled by some regex flavors.

Comment: `(?<=^|\P{L})` is variable length, `^` is zero-length and `\P{L}` is one character length. Have a look at your regex101 [updated](https://regex101.com/r/R2t2ik/2), it deosn' work with Python.

Comment: @Toto Oh yes... what a pitty :-( Well, in this case I don't know how to solve it. I'll need the help of a regex specialist (which isn't my case).